# Unable to add HTML snippet in a letterhead email template in Salesforce Classic

Tags: email-template, email-alert, letterhead

My requirement is to use HTML to display buttons on an Email Template with Letterhead, but I am not able to add html to a letterhead email template. Can someone please help? Right now it is as it is displaying the html content which I had added.

[image]

Comment: If you want to use letterheads, then you will need to use the Rich text editor by creating an `HTML template with Classic letterhead` which has ability to make text bold italics, add an image and then add a link to text or the image. Else, you can create a custom email template which is always without letterhead (This is in classic view)

Comment: Does that mean that there is no way to add a button to the email template with letterhead?

Comment: You can always add an image of the button and then add a link to it. That is possible in `HTML template with Classic letterhead`

Comment: Thanks, @Manjit, let me try it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use letterheads, then you will need to use the Rich text editor by creating an **HTML template with Classic letterhead** which has the ability to make text bold italics, add an image and then add a link to text or the image. Else, you can create a custom email template which is always without letterhead (This is in classic view).

You can always add an image of the button and then add a link to it. That is possible in **HTML template with Classic letterhead**. It is a bit old school but it works. The one downside I see is that when viewing in the browser, it navigates the link in the current tab.